# How to save a Bundle?

Tags: android, gridview, bundle, save, onpause

Which one is better to save Bundle: OnSaveInstanceState or OnPause in order to save Bundle in case or rotation and redrawing of a GridView containing images that have been modified?

Answer (score 0):

`onPause()` is called whenever your activity loses it's foreground status, and subsequently when it comes to the foreground, it's counterpart `onResume()` is called. So, this is where you would check your UI-related information (eg. updating).

`onSaveInstanceState()` is where you should save your Bundle. The retrieval of your bundle (activity state info) can be done in either `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`.